# Untoggle Previous Menus on click of the Next Menu Header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, frontend

I have created a menu using CSS and Javascript. When I click on a menu topic (Header) it gets toggled and shows the sub categories.

What I need it to do is.. when I click on any other menu headers the previously toggled (shown) sub category should untoggle (hide) and the currently active menu header should be toggled with its sub categories. How can I achieve this?

here is my code..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //Hide the tooglebox when page load
  $(".togglebox").hide();

  //slide up and down when click over heading 2
  $("h2").click(function(){

    // slide toggle effect set to slow you can set it to fast too.
    $(this).next(".togglebox").slideToggle("slow");
    $(".toggleBox").hide();
return true;
  });
});
```

### HTML

now it is kind of OK, but there are some weird movements when I click on it. Here is my remaining HTML code.

```
<html>                     
<head>
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"   type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="toggle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
<h2 style="background-color:#DAD0D0;">NOKIA</h2>
            <div class="togglebox">
                <div class="content">
                <center><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;"> NOKIA 8320     </a></center>
                </div>
            </div>


    <h2 style="background-color:#EEE6E6;">SAMSUNG</h2>      
            <div class="togglebox">
                <div class="content">
                <center><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;">SAMSUNG 3242C </a></center>
                <center><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;">SAMSUNG 3423C </a></center>
                <center><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;">SAMSUNG 7642C </a></center>
                </div>
            </div>

    <h2 style="background-color:#DAD0D0;">SONY ERICSSON</h2>        
            <div class="togglebox">
                <div class="content">
                <center><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;">SAMSUNG 3242C </a></center>
                <center><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;">SAMSUNG 3423C </a></center>
                <center><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;">SAMSUNG 7642C </a></center>
                </div>
            </div>      

    <h2 style="background-color:#EEE6E6;">ALCATEL</h2>      
            <div class="togglebox">
                <div class="content">
                <center><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;">SAMSUNG   3242C </a></center>
                <center><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;">SAMSUNG    3423C </a></center>
                <center><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;">SAMSUNG    7642C </a></center>
                </div>
            </div>
            </td>

            <td width="70%"> 
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

### CSS

```
h2 {
padding:10px;
font-size:10px;

color:#243953;

/* border: 1px solid #a9a9a9;
-moz-border-radius: 7px; /* Rounder Corner 
   -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
-khtml-border-radius: 7px; */
text-align:center;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
margin-bottom:10px;
 margin: 0px;

}
.togglebox {
background-color:#F7F3F3;
border: 0px solid #a9a9a9;
/* Rounder Corner */
/* -moz-border-radius: 7px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
-khtml-border-radius: 7px; */
overflow: hidden;
font-size: 1.2em;
width: 196px;
clear: both;
margin-bottom:0px;
margin-top:0px;
}
.togglebox .content {
padding: 20px;
```

Comment: 1. please add 4 spaces in front of each code lines. 2. toggle mean switching between 2 states, so you can't really "untoggle". 3. could you add some html sample?

Comment: @user if you are satisfied with one of the answers,  please, mark it as RIGHT ANSWER!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// slide toggle effect set to slow you can set it to fast too.
 $(".togglebox").hide();
 $(this).next(".togglebox").slideToggle("slow");
```

you have a capital 'B' in your hide code, `$(".toggleBox").hide();`  and you should swap the order of the actions hide all the "toggleboxes" (not the current one though, see below)  first before triggering the `H2`'s next slidedown

---

#### Example [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/NtGmm/)

edited as the above code means you can't toggle the current togglebox

```
// slide toggle effect set to slow you can set it to fast too.
 var tb = $(this).next(".togglebox");
 
 $(".togglebox").not(tb).slideUp(); 
 $(tb).slideToggle("slow");
```

---

Because of later addition of more code to question;

#### Updated  [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/RLQd4/)

Comment: Im facing some issues in above mentioned question please help me out. the full code is added to the same question above.

Comment: @user you can add "slow" to the `slideUp("slow")` function as well so it seems a smoother transition when one is opening and another is closing OR you can simply change it to `hide()` too though that may seem more jerky? -  and when I pasted your code I found it better to give the first table cell a width (200px;) then remove the widths on the togglebox that way the headings and content stay the same width - I renew a fiddle with your updated code

Comment: @user755673 - I've updated my answer with a fiddle that uses your code, and added the changes mentioned in my comment above, does that look better?

Comment: You might also be better to add a proper Doctype before the `<html>` tag e.g. : `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN"
 "*http*://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-html40-19980424/strict.dtd">
<html>`

Answer (score 0):

I prepared a DEMO **[H E R E](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/NQCVW/)**

Let me know if this suits your needs.